# How can I get Asp.net MVC add view dialog out of Views folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4

Since I followed [this article](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/03/ASPNET-MVC-Implement-Theme-Folders-using-a-Custom-ViewEngine.aspx) to implement a theme engine in Asp.net MVC website.
But by doing this I can't have "Add View" dialog by right click on ~/Themes/ folder. By default "Add View" dialog can only show up when I click ~/Views/ folder. Can I have any chance to set it show up for ~/Themes/ Folder?

**Edit:**
My Teammate want to change some options in [asp.net mvc T4 template](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx), he put CodeTemplates in website root folder. He can't find the options from his T4 by doing :  **Add --> New Item ---> MVC View Page**

It seems Views folder can't be changed to another name in ASP.net MVC. Otherwise you will lose those T4 related items in VS IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Since three weeks past, no accept answer for this question so I guess this is by design issue can't be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Add --> New Item ---> MVC View Page** everywhere in your project.

Comment: Yes, This method can help user create a View, but user won't get any T4 related addtional helper template in the view. Any other good ideas?

Comment: Sorry the link you mentioned seems to be broken.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea +1 to your comment

Comment: To get T4 generation, you will have to add to the root "Views" folder.  You could create into "Views", and then just copy/drag the generated file into your Themes folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can not add view with right click if your return type of method is not ActionResult.